# How to set/change ng-init value with a function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-init

I need to change ng-init value with function in controller

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="FilterManager" data-ng-init="FilterVisible=false;" >
    <p>name: {{ FilterVisible}}</p>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-ng-click="setFilter();">click</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function FilterManager($scope) {
    $scope.setFilter = function() {
        FilterVisible=true;
    };
}

</script>
```

Why this code doesn't work?
Thanks

@PSL your code works fine, but if I'm in ng-repeat how can I do the same?

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="c in columns">
        <div ng-init="FilterVisible=false" data-ng-click="setFilter();">{{c.name}} {{FilterVisible}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.columns = [{'name': 1}, {'name': 2}, {'name': 3}];
    $scope.setFilter = function() {
        FilterVisible=true;
    };
});
```

Comment: What is in `...` ? How are you getting the variable `$scope` ?

Comment: ... is the definition of controller

Comment: Where is the controller in your posted html? `FilterVisible`  is not a global variable that angular sets. It is attached to the scope. http://jsbin.com/cowuxowoqi/1/edit

Comment: What error do you see in the console? `Why this code doesn't work?` could mean a lot of things. Which version of angular you are using?

Comment: There are no errors, but it doesn't work

Comment: try here http://jsfiddle.net/c2hj9mkL/1/